# How to access class functions in JS click handler?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a card game in HTML, CSS, JS and I have a class `PlayerHand` that contains functions `raiseCard()`, `lowerCard()`, `addCards()` among others. When I use `addCards()` SVG images are essentially added to the HTML and I assign a clickHandler to each of the cards.

The click handler on the cards uses the functions `raiseCard()` and `lowerCard()` of `PlayerHand` and it also needs to know which card was clicked, to know which card to raise or lower. The issue I'm having is that when I define the clickHandler inside `PlayerHand` class, I cannot use the `this` keyword to access the class functions `lowerCard()` and `raiseCard()`. Because `this` is gonna be the card that I clicked. I'm aware of `bind`, but I stil need to be able to know the card clicked and access the class functions.

Any idea how I can do this? Am I perhaps designing this in a stupid way?

```
class PlayerHand {
  
  addCards(cards, eventHandler = null) {
        if (cards.length + this.getCards() > this.MAX_CARDS_ON_HAND) return; // Don't allow more than 13 cards on hand

        cards.forEach((cid) => {
            const card = document.createElement("card-t");
            card.setAttribute("cid", cid);
            card.addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false);
            this.container.appendChild(card);
        });
    }

  raiseCard(cardElement) {
    cardElement.style.transform = "translate(0px, calc(var(--raise-card-on-click) * -1))";
  }

  lowerCard(cardElement) {
    cardElement.style.transform = "none";
  }

  cardClickHandler() {
    const LOWERED = 0;
    let cardHeight = LOWERED;
    const transform = this.style.transform.match(/\d+/g); // Get X and Y coordinate
    if (transform !== null) cardHeight = transform["1"]; // Get the Y coordinate

    if (cardHeight === LOWERED) {
      thisClass.raiseCard(thisCard); // I need to access the class function and pass in the card object that was clicked
    } else {
        thisClass.lowerCard(thisCard); // I need to access the class function and pass in the card object that was clicked
    }
  }
}
```

Another method I tried was to define the clickHandler outside of the class `PlayerHand` and then I'd use the `player` object inside of the click handler, but I didn't quite like this either, as it's not very dynamic by defining the object inside the clickHandler statically.

```
player = new PlayerHand();

function clickHandler() {
  ...
  if (cardHeight === LOWERED) {
    player.raiseCard(this);
    } else {
      player.lowerCard(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: See [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: `document.createElement("card-t");` ? the parameter for `.createElement()` is a `tagName` (ex. `"div"`, `"a"`, `"fieldset"`, etc.)

Comment: @zer00ne Correct, I'm using a library for creating playing cards that implements a "card-t" as web component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you essentially need *two* objects (the card element and `PlayerHand` instance), you'll need *two* arguments: one can be `this`, but other should be a normal argument. As the `cardClickHandler` is defined as a method on the `PlayerHand` prototype, it would be most natural to let `this` be the `PlayerHand` instance.

So attach the event handler as follows:

```
card.addEventListener("click", () => eventHandler.call(this, card), false);
```

And then the method would be something like:

```
  cardClickHandler(card) {
    const LOWERED = 0;
    let cardHeight = LOWERED;
    const transform = card.style.transform.match(/\d+/g);
    if (transform !== null) cardHeight = transform["1"];

    if (cardHeight === LOWERED) {
        this.raiseCard(card);
    } else {
        this.lowerCard(card);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind the card you want to retrieve with the argument of the click handler function:

```js
class PlayerHand {
  
  addCards(cards, eventHandler = null) {
        // ...
        cards.forEach((cid) => {
            const card = document.createElement("card-t");
            card.setAttribute("cid", cid);
            card.addEventListener("click", this.cardClickHandler.bind(this, card), false);
            this.container.appendChild(card);
        });
    }

  // ...

  cardClickHandler(_event, card) {
    const LOWERED = 0;
    let cardHeight = LOWERED;
    const transform = this.style.transform.match(/\d+/g); // Get X and Y coordinate
    if (transform !== null) cardHeight = transform["1"]; // Get the Y coordinate

    if (cardHeight === LOWERED) {
      this.raiseCard(card); // retrieve here the card you passed as argument in the event handler
    } else {
        this.lowerCard(card); // idem
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you bind arguments to a function, they get prepended to the arguments that are provided by the caller. So `card` will be the first argument to `cardClickHandler()`, before `_event` provided by `addEventListener()`.

```
class PlayerHand {
  
  addCards(cards, eventHandler = null) {
        // ...
        cards.forEach((cid) => {
            const card = document.createElement("card-t");
            card.setAttribute("cid", cid);
            card.addEventListener("click", this.cardClickHandler.bind(this, card), false);
            this.container.appendChild(card);
        });
    }

  // ...

  cardClickHandler(card, _event) {
    const LOWERED = 0;
    let cardHeight = LOWERED;
    const transform = this.style.transform.match(/\d+/g); // Get X and Y coordinate
    if (transform !== null) cardHeight = transform["1"]; // Get the Y coordinate

    if (cardHeight === LOWERED) {
      this.raiseCard(card); // retrieve here the card you passed as argument in the event handler
    } else {
        this.lowerCard(card); // idem
    }
  }
}
```